# finding square cost function theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I am new to theano and neural networks. I am trying to evaluate square cost function `summation_over_components_of_y((y-x)**2)` where x is a constant and y is a vector.

```
components,updates = theano.scan(fn=lambda coeff, power, free_var:
                                   coeff * (free_var ** power),
                                outputs_info=None,
                                sequences=[input_vector, full_range],
                                non_sequences=x)
```

I used scan function to get components. How to get the required value `sum((component-constant)**2)`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm pretty sure some machine learning code examples has the answer, which can be easily googled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
theano.tensor.sum((y-x)*(y-x))
```

A side note, if `x` is scalar constant, it will be broadcasted.